# How to count steps for complete the linear Search

Tags: java, linear-search

I have an array,I Search one element using linear Search.But I want to
count after how many  steps I got the result. But I am not able to
count the steps ,I am able to only search the element from the
array,But not able to find the steps.
LinearSearhc.java

```
public class ArrayRotation {
public static int linearSearch(int []arr,int x){
    int n = arr.length-1;
    for (int i=0;i<=n;i++){
        if (arr[i]== x)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayRotation arrRotation = new ArrayRotation();
        int arr[]={4,56,44,152,54,845};
        int x = 26;
        int result = linearSearch(arr,x);
        if (result == -1)
            System.out.println("searching element not Present in this array");
        else
            System.out.println("Searching element present at the  index position" +result);




    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are doing a linear search and returning the index of the item, doesn't what you are returning indicate the number of steps also? `Number of steps = value returned + 1`

Answer (score 1):

Since we cannot return 2 values in a method in Java, we can instead return a Array with 2 values, one being if the linear search found the element and other being the amount of steps.
Change the linearSearch Method to

```
public static int[] linearSearch(int []arr,int x){
    int steps = 0;
    int[] result = {-1,0};
    int n = arr.length-1;
    for (int i=0;i<=n;i++){
        steps++;
        if (arr[i]== x) {
            result[0] = i;
            break;
        }        
    }
    result[1] = steps;
    return result;
}
```

Then change the code in the Main Method to take in a array as result and the first index will be the Integer if found and the second will be the amount of steps.
Example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
     int arr[]={4,56,44,152,54,845};
     
     int[]result = linearSearch(arr,54);
        if (result[0] == -1)
            System.out.println("searching element not Present in this array");
        else
            System.out.println("Searching element present at the  index position " +result[0]+" in "+result[1]+" steps");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Since is a linear search it will search all the elements to say -1 or stop when it finds it

you can count the steps adding a counter inside the for loop

```
    class Playground {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayRotation arrRotation = new ArrayRotation();
        int arr[]={4,56,44,152,54,845};
        int x = 26;
        int result = arrRotation.linearSearch(arr,x);
        if (result == -1)
            System.out.println("searching element not Present in this array");
        else
            System.out.println("Searching element present at the  index position " +result);

    }
}

public class ArrayRotation {

    public static int linearSearch(int []arr, int x){
    int n = arr.length-1;
    int counter = 0;
    int position = -1;

    for (int i=0; i <= n; i++) {
        counter++;
        if (arr[i] == x) {
            position = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("searching element stop after counting " + counter);


    return position;
    }
}
```